# Navigate from userActivity handler to other view

Tags: ios, swift

I want to navigate to a view from a Siri suggestion. The problem is that I need the normal app flow. So first I load the normal view, which redirects and it that view I need to do an action.

But how do I know that it is called from a suggestion? I did try to set an UserDefaults key. But sometimes that property is not set (it's not set when I check the value because sync issues).

Also the notifications center is not working as I can't set the observer at the right time.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
    {
         if userActivity.activityType == "myId" {

                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "openViaSiri")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("openViaSiri"), object: nil)

           }



        return true
    }
```

What is a good solution for this?